# TinyMCE Issue in Events on execCommand

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

There is an issue with the TinyMCE editor. When I insert a table from the toolbar, the execCommand is triggered, and it should contain mceInsertTable. However, two events are fired: mceInsertContent and mceInsertTable. I would like to know why this is happening and if anyone can help me understand how to deal with it. Additionally, I've noticed that there is no way to capture the Shift+Tab event simultaneously, as we can do in Vanilla JS.

I tried using if/else statements for my purpose as of now, and didn't got any way to capture Shift+Tab event.